# Prove $\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n+1} + .... + \frac{1}{2n} > 0.63 $

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, summation, harmonic-numbers

I need to prove this: 
$\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n+1} + .... + \frac{1}{2n} > 0.63 $.

I know its $\log{(2)} $ and it's something like $\int_{0}^{1} \ \frac{dx}{1+x}\ =  \log{(2)}$, but I don't know the steps between those.

Comment: In fact $\log_e(2) \approx 0.693147$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Integral_test
Similarly you can show that $$\int_{n}^{2n}\frac{1}{x}dx<\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}+\dots+\frac{1}{2n}$$
Notice that: $$\int_{n}^{2n}\frac{1}{x}dx=\log(2n)-\log(n)=\log\left(\frac{2n}{n}\right)=\log(2)$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $(a_n)$ be the sequence
$$a_n= \frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1} + \dots + \frac{1}{2n},$$
then $a_1=1.5$ and $a_{n+1}-a_n= \frac{1}{2n+2} +\frac{1}{2n+1} -\frac{1}{n}<0$, then the sequence is decreasing, as u have noticed that $a_n \to \log  2$, it won't be hard to figure out that $a_n>\log 2 \approx 0.693$ for all integers $n>0$.

Comment: You right, but if an is decreasing that mean an >a(n+1) and an->log(2), so i didn't aproved the an+1 is also ---> log(2), a(n+1) start from 1/n+1, thats make the difference.

Comment: @OmarAbuAsbe   Suppose that $(a_n)$ is a strictly decreasing and convergent sequence that has a limit $l$ then $a_n>l$ for all integers $n$.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
\frac1n+\frac1{n+1}+\cdots+\frac1{2n}
&\ge\int_n^{2n+1}\frac1x\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\log\left(2+\frac1n\right)\\[3pt]
&\gt\log(2)
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the desired inequality by checking it directly for $n=1$ and $2$ and then proving, by induction, the *stronger* inequality

$${1\over n}+{1\over n+1}+\cdots+{1\over2n}\gt{2\over3}+{3\over4n-1}\qquad\text{for }n\ge3$$

The base case is

$${1\over3}+{1\over4}+{1\over5}+{1\over6}={19\over20}\gt{31\over33}={2\over3}+{3\over11}$$

(the key calculation is $33\cdot19=627\gt620=20\cdot31$), and the induction step boils down to verifying the inequality

$${3\over4n-1}+{1\over2n+1}+{1\over 2n+2}-{1\over n}\gt{3\over4n+3}$$

which is messy but doable.

In case anyone is curious where the stronger inequality came from, I picked the $2\over3$ as a convenient fraction that's less than $\ln2\approx.69$ and then did a bunch of work to find something of the form $a\over bn+c$ to tack on that would make the induction step work.

Comment: i asked my teacher on college and he said that this is not enough to prove the a(n+1) > 0.63 because the sequence is decreasing so the a(n+1) - a(n) not the best way. he said i have to think on another think to solve it with induction

Comment: @OmarAbuAsbe, your teach is correct in saying that the decreasing nature of the sequence prevents you from using straightforward induction to prove an inequality like $a_n\gt{2\over3}$.  That's why I had to tack on the ${3\over4n-1}$.  If you (or your teacher) check my answer, you will see that the induction works.